# Is it possible to exclude special buffers from the v:oldfiles list?

Tags: neovim

I use the `:oldfiles` command a lot, but it's annoying that it gets populated with things like terminal or help buffers. My understanding is that any buffer for which a mark exist will be listed by the command, so if I close Neovim while the focus is on a help or terminal buffer, I will see those next time on the lists.

I know I can use the `r` option of the ShaDa file to filter out some paths by a prefix, but I wonder if there's a wider solution, after all I just care about files whose `buftype` is empty

Answer (score 1):

In the end I wrote [a function](https://github.com/tssm/.config/blob/master/nvim/lua/configs/behaviour.fnl#L15) that wipes out all buffers whose type is `help`, which is executed by the `VimLeavePre` event, i.e. right before the ShaDa file is written

Comment: Please also include the relevant code in the post so it remains self-contained

Comment: Hi Tae, it seems that you have made some change in your repository and the function is not where it was before. Could you update the link?

Comment: Continuation of what Vivian said: always provide permalink instead of link relative to a movie HEAD. That will ensure the link never gets out of sync (as long as GH is online).